# Failure to compile SCONS in MARSS implementation

Tags: c++, scons

I am experiencing a problem when implementing Scons 2.5.0 in Linux Mint 17.2 (Virtually created using Virtual BOX)

Following the blog provided from the official website : http://www.marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Getting_Started

I'm able to setup the compiling environment for Scons, but the problem occurs when i execute this command:

> `$ scons -Q`

This results in the following error messages:

> scons: *** [ptlsim/build/cache/bus.o] Error 1
>
> g++: error: unrecognized command line option
>   ‘-fdiagnostics-color=always’
>
> scons: *** [ptlsim/build/cache/cacheController.o] Error 1

I have tried updating the g++ version to 5.0, but it still doesn't seem to recognize the `‘-fdiagnostics-color=always’` command.

Any ideas/help will be appreciated in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the offending line 33:

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ' -fdiagnostics-color=always ')
```

from the file `./ptlsim/SConstruct`. Coloured output isn't required for the build, and gcc/g++ should use a reasonable default like `auto`for the setting above anyway.

Comment: [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html#Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options) "The default depends" .